Reading JSON files in R and creating a dataset
I am trying to create a dataset in R from 3k JSON files.
(This is the data: Nauman, F. (2023). Clothing Dataset for Second-Hand Fashion (Version 1) [Data set].Available at: Zenodo. https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.8386668 )
My goal is to have the data in R as a dataset/table so I can clean it and run some regressions. This is for a school paper, I'm quite new to R.
Here is my code:
### Reading JSON files

library(rjson)

# Instantiate the data object to hold the JSON details
master_data <- NULL

# Gather the names of the JSON file held in a folder
file_list <- list.files(path = "data/json_files")

# Loop through the list of files, read the JSON details, 
#   convert to data frame and append to the data object
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  file_details <- fromJSON(file = paste0("data/json_files/",file_list[i]))
  master_data <- rbind(master_data, as.data.frame(file_details))
}

# Check the data object
master_data

#This is the error I'm getting:
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  the arguments imply different numbers of rows : 1, 0

#I tried bind_rows()  to bind uneven rows

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  
  file_details <- fromJSON(file = paste0("data/json_files/",file_list[i]))
  
  master_data <- bind_rows(master_data, as.data.frame(file_details))
  
}
#that doesn't work either, same error

#I tried rbind.fill() from the package plyr, 

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){  
  file_details <- fromJSON(file = paste0("data/json_files/",file_list[i]))
  
  master_data <- rbind.fill(master_data, as.data.frame(file_details))
  
}

#that doesn't work either, same error
#Any ideas will be appreaciated. Thank you!

rbind or bind_rows in a loop is called "growing an object", where your data gets bigger every time through the loop. It's an anti-pattern because it's really inefficient.  Generally it's advised to read all the files into a list with, e.g., file_data = lapply(file_list, \(x) as.data.frame(fromJSON(paste0("data/json_files/", file_list)))). This will give you a list with all of the individual data frames. You can then attempt to combine them all at once with combined_data = bind_rows(file_data).

That still might not work if you've got irregularities in some of your files, but you at least have them all loaded so you can inspect them and try out which ones are causing problems. You can try binding together smaller subsets to narrow down where the problem is, e.g., if bind_rows(file_data[1:1000]) works then there's no issues in the first 1000.

I used the CRAN package rjsoncons.
I listed the full path to files, so I didn't need to construct them by pasting onto a base file name
file_list <- list.files(
    "~/tmp/circular_fashion",
    pattern = ".*json",
    recursive = TRUE,
    full.names = TRUE
)

I noticed that one of the files is not valid JSON. I found this by iterating through each file and trying simply to read it using j_query(). If reading failed, I printed out the file name and error, and used 'NA' for the content.
json <- vapply(file_list, function(file) {
    tryCatch({
        rjsoncons::j_query(file)
    }, error = function(e) {
        message(file, ": ", conditionMessage(e))
        NA_character_
    })
}, character(1))


The output is
oct2022/2022-10-17/labels_2022_10_17_07_40_32.json: Extra comma at line 12 and column 6

and the JSON file is actually incorrect:
...
    "colors": [
        "red",
        
        
      
    
    ],
...

I removed the corrupt data from the JSON strings that I've read in
json <- json[!is.na(json)]

and then made the R character vector of JSON objects into an array-of-objects
json_array <- paste0("[", paste(json, collapse = ","), "]")

Finally, I used j_pivot to change the array-of-objects to an R tibble
tbl <- rjsoncons::j_pivot(json_array, as = "tibble")

Here's the result:
> tbl
# A tibble: 3,052 × 22
   brand     brandtext category type  size  colors season pilling condition price
   <chr>     <list>    <chr>    <chr> <chr> <list> <chr>    <int>     <int> <chr>
 1 Everest   <chr [1]> Children Wint… "104" <chr>  Winter       3         3 50-1…
 2 Everest   <chr [1]> Children Wint… "104" <chr>  Winter       3         3 50-1…
 3 Not in t… <chr [1]> Men      Jack… "M "  <chr>  Autumn       5         5 >400 
 4 Everest   <chr [1]> Children Jack… "146" <chr>  Autumn       5         5 100-…
 5 Etirel    <chr [1]> Ladies   Wint… "40"  <chr>  Winter       4         3 100-…
 6 Lindex    <chr [1]> Children Rain… "98"  <chr>  Spring       4         2 <50  
 7 Not in t… <chr [1]> Ladies   Dress "42"  <chr>  Autumn       5         5 100-…
 8 Not in t… <chr [1]> Men      Trou… "Non… <chr>  Autumn       5         4 100-…
 9 Not in t… <chr [1]> Ladies   Blou… "42"  <chr>  Spring       5         5 50-1…
10 Park Lane <chr [1]> Men      Swea… "M "  <chr>  Autumn       5         5 100-…
# ℹ 3,042 more rows
# ℹ 12 more variables: annotator <list>, cut <list>, pattern <chr>, trend <chr>,
#   smell <list>, stains <chr>, holes <list>, damage <chr>, material <chr>,
#   comment <chr>, usage <chr>, weight <list>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

